# NaCl and shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory, google-nativeclient

I have application that write some date in linux shared memory (/dev/shm/datahere).
I need to show this data in browser with using google native client.
it is real? How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to dig pretty on the Internet, but I found a solution:
Just out of the browser can not access because of the sandbox, but there is a Chrome Apps, which with the help NaCl can access the file system.

To build Chrome Apps included with NaCl and access to the file system, do the following:

1. Download nacl_sdk. Update it, to get examples (pepperX)
2. In a file `nacl_sdk/pepper_46/tools/common.mk` find a line **SANDBOX_ARGS: = --no-sandbox** and change to:

> **SANDBOX_ARGS: = --no-sandbox --allow-no-sandbox-job --nacl-dangerous-no-sandbox-nonsfinacl**

**CHROME_ENV ?=**, to:

> **CHROME_ENV=NACL_DANGEROUS_ENABLE_FILE_ACCESS=1**

2.1 If you use run_package, then you need write in a file common.mk:

> run_package: check_for_chrome all
>       @echo "$(TOOLCHAIN) $(CONFIG)" > $(CURDIR)/run_package_config
>       **Exec=env NACL_DANGEROUS_ENABLE_FILE_ACCESS=1** "$(CHROME_PATH)" --load-and-launch-app=$(CURDIR) $(CHROME_ARGS)

3. In the Makefile of project need to add this:

> ```
> LIBS = ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread nacl_io
> DEPS = nacl_io
> CFLAGS = -Wall
> SOURCES = <filename> .cc
>
> # Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:
> $ (foreach dep, $ (DEPS), $ (eval $ (call DEPEND_RULE, $ (dep))))
> $ (foreach src, $ (SOURCES), $ (eval $ (call COMPILE_RULE, $ (src), $ (CFLAGS))))
>
> # The PNaCl workflow uses both an unstripped and finalized / stripped binary.
> ```

4. Code example. it is very important - do not read /dev/shm read /var/run/shm:

> ```
> int file;
> file = open("/var/run/shm/helloworld.txt", O_RDONLY);
> char buffer[1024];
> memset(&buffer, 0, 1024);
> read(file, buffer, 13);
> pp::Var var_reply(buffer);
> PostMessage(var_reply);
> ```

P.S. Maybe it is not a good solution, but it work for me